# Different os.Getenv("PATH") results from shell and double-click executable

Tags: linux, go, path

In my Go program I call os.Getenv("PATH") on Linux (Debian) and I get different results when running the program from within the shell or when double-clicking the executable icon in my file browser or on my desktop.

I have edited my ~/.profile to include the go binary in the PATH like so:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

as suggested the [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) Go instrutions.

When I run my os.Getenv("PATH") program from the shell it outputs:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`

but when I run it by double-clicking the executable file it outputs:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`

This suggests that double-clicking an icon will not initialize the variables with the `profile` commands. How can I now get the PATH that I want, i.e. including the additional directories, from my Go program?

Comment: Have you logged out completely since you modified your `.profile`?

Comment: Yes, I have logged out and back in. As I said, it is working when run from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what PATH you want.

Your program gets environment variables from the context it was executed from.
You need to modify your PATH variable for your system to "know" about executables provided with the Go release. And you usually don't need 'usr/local/go/bin' PATH when you already have a compiled binary file.

Comment: But that is my question: what IS the context that an application is run from when I double-click it? And how would I change my PATH variable globally if not in ~/.profile? Note that I also already tried changing it in my ~/.bashrc and /etc/bash.baschrc as well and it did not work.

Comment: not sure about context you run it from when you double-click. But you can modify /etc/environment file to change it globally.

Comment: I just tried editing /etc/environment but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Did you restart your PC after you changed /etc/environment? logout-login doesn't work in this case. And you should not write 'export' in /etc/environment.

Comment: Just did, doesn't help it.